# Why Symbol.iterator was designed of type Symbol?

Tags: javascript, iterator, symbols

I am learning about `Symbol` and iterators in JavaScript.
I've read and watched few videos about them, so they are now more or less clear.

I just would like to understand what my textbook (Eloquent JavaScript) means with this:

> Note that the `next`, `value` and `done` property names are plain strings, not symbols. Only `Simbol.iterator`, which is likely to be added to a lot of different objects, is an actual symbol.

Why does a property that is likely to be found in different objects need to be a symbol?

Can `objOne.iterator` and `objTwo.iterator` as regular properties create problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbols are unique properties on objects. If one creates a symbol and puts it on an object, there's no chance of any other symbol being put on the object and causing bugs due to a name collision.

Using `Symbol.iterator` as *the unique symbol* for iterators for potentially *any* object eliminates the possibility of property collision bugs. For example, if `.iterator` was the (string) property used instead, objects could no longer easily have the `.iterator` property *unless* it specifically implemented the iterator protocol.

Also consider legacy code that might have had objects with an `iterator` property, but weren't intended to be ES2015+ iterators - what should happen with them? Better to use a Symbol so as not to have to worry about any of that stuff.

`anyPossibleObj[Symbol.iterator]` is much safer than `anyPossibleObj.anyStringYouCouldThinkOf`.

Comment: Oh all right, I got it, they made "iterator" a symbol property to avoid making it the name of a built-in property. Thank you very much for the datailed answer!

Comment: Symbol properties are also excluded by some functions like, [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)